# Case When vs. Count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have problem with this query on MySQL.

If tried this version :

```
mysql>  SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    myCode,
    myState
FROM
    `tbl_2016`
WHERE
    `myCode` LIKE '%XI10-2-020012%'
GROUP BY
    `myState`;
```

The output is :

```
+----------+---------------+--------------------------------+
| COUNT(*) | myCode        | myState                        |
+----------+---------------+--------------------------------+
|        5 | XI10-2-020012 | NULL                           |
|        4 | XI10-2-020012 | ACTIVE                         |
|        1 | XI10-2-020012 | NOT ACTIVE                     |
+----------+---------------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set
```

But if tried this other versione with **CASE WHEN** syntax :

```
mysql> SELECT
    myCode,
    COUNT(
        CASE
        WHEN myState IN (
            'Active'
        ) THEN
            1
        ELSE
            0
        END
    ) AS `Active`,
    COUNT(
        CASE
        WHEN myState IN (
            'Not Active'
        ) THEN
            1
        ELSE
            0
        END
    ) AS `Not Active`
FROM
    `tbl_2016`
WHERE
        `myCode` LIKE '%XI10-2-020012%'
GROUP BY
    `myState`;
```

The output is different than the first version :

```
+---------------+--------+------------+
| myCode        | Active | Not Active |
+---------------+--------+------------+
| XI10-2-020012 |      4 |          4 |
+---------------+--------+------------+
1 row in set
```

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance, my code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM instead of COUNT in second version